# RecurringJob or BackgroundJob + loop for infinite task

Tags: hangfire

I'm wondering to use Hangfire to program an update task. I want this task to be executed every time. So when the task finish I want to execute it again.

I don't know if the best method to use is RecurringJob or use a loop and a BackgroundJob for it.

What do you recommend me? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecurringJob which triggers every x minutes or x hours (based on your requirement - can set CRON expression) , which will trigger the task/work after every such interval. This you need to use in conjunction with DisableConcurrentExecution attribute, so that multiple instances of same task are not triggered, also this attributes makes sure once your first instance is completely, then only second one will be processed.

Alternatively, you can use BackGroundJob to enqueue a task/job but this does the processing of job only one time. So you need to write some code to check this Jobs status and re-enqueue the same job again, once the first is completed. In this approach you need to write some code to do that.

I would suggest the best way is to use RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate in conjunction with DisableConcurrentExecution